# Java FileReader memory usage pattern

Tags: java, memory, filereader

It seems like FileReader is reading a file into memory but I don't want it to. Based on memory use of java reported by the OS, my simple program climbs from initial ~11MB to over 60MB, while reading a ~50MB file. Just to baseline this, the following program without FileReader runs for about 30 seconds and remains pegged at ~11MB memory use.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int count=0;
        while ((count++) < 30000) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

However, once I add FileReader, the memory use will climb from ~11MB to over 60MB before the java process ends. But according to the doc, "FileReader is meant for reading streams of characters." What am I missing?

```
import java.io.FileReader;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("/tmp/big.txt");
        int charCode = -1;
        while ((charCode = reader.read()) > -1) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the increase in memory use is due to loading in all the file I/O support software and that it's just coincidental that the increase in memory use and the file size are both ~50MB. Have you tried the experiment with a file of much different size?

Comment: I thought that as well, which is why I have the millisecond sleeps in there so you can actually see it climb from starting ~11MB to over 60 slowly and evenly, presumably as the file is read, and then the program terminates. Here are some other observations:

Comment: For a 17MB binary file, it climbs from ~12MB immediately to ~35MB then quickly onto ~96MB and remains there the rest of the execution. For a 448MB binary file it does pretty much exactly the same thing as 17MB. So, certainly, memory use remains well below the nearly half-gig file size. I think you are right and will accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the increase in memory use is due to loading in all the file I/O support software and that it's just coincidental that the increase in memory use and the file size are both ~50MB. You can check this by trying the experiment with significantly different file sizes. If you're trying to minimize memory usage, you might also try calling `System.gc();` just before calling `Thread.sleep(1);`. The underlying I/O framework may be generated garbage (reallocating buffers, etc.) even though your code is pretty much garbage-free.

Comment: Thanks. In conjunction with my observations above, the same 448MB binary file load, with your System.gc() call every 1000th character quickly pegged memory to around 39MB and never higher. So, looks like you are right about underlying I/O object consumption.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a JVM, this JVM allocates **virtual** memory from the underlying system. Therefore, the memory is really allocated only when something is written into a memory page. This means that memory is really allocated when you instanciate a new object, for instance. Because instanciating a new object writes some data into memory. But when the object is discarded, the JVM does not tell the operating system about that. So the memory is still allocated, from the point of view of the operating system. But of course, later, new objects *could* be reallocated on the same memory location by the JVM, since the JVM knows which memory space is free. But this is absolutely not enforced by many JVMs: they have no need to allocate new objects in the same memory place of previously discarded object, because they have a big amount of **virtual** memory.

So, when invoking `reader.read()` one time, the system library allocates some memory for temporary objects (data read), and unreference those objects before returning. But the garbage collect that collects those objects does not tell the OS about the corresponding blocks.

It is like having no TRIM with a SSD disk: the disk is not aware of discarded and available blocks.

Anyway, somebody could create a JVM that would have a different memory usage behaviour, because the behaviour is left to the implementor.

Comment: But what object in my code is getting created and discarded? From my read, the reader and charCode are allocated only once, ever.

Comment: The function reader.read() has to read and store data temporarily. This function allocates and discards memory objects at each call.

Comment: Great, thanks Alexandre. I think you and Ted are saying basically the same thing so will up-vote yours.